# Problem with a triple integral domain

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am confused about how to proceed with this exercise, which asks me to calculate the volume of $A = \left\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3; x^2+y^2 \leq z, z^2-2 \leq x^2+y^2\right\}$

I thought about polar coordinates, which give me

$$R^2 \leq z ~~~~~~~~~~~ R^2 \geq z^2-2$$

The range for $\theta$ is the same $[0, 2\pi]$ but how do I determine the range for $R$ or $z$?

$R^2 \leq z$ would imply $-z \leq R \leq z$ but it doesn't seem correct, also because the other condition $R^2 \geq z^2-2$ would give me a different range for $z$.

I need clarification on how to proceed and how to reason...

Comment: Can't you simply use $R^2 \leq z \leq \sqrt{R^2 + 2}$? And then solve for the intersection to find bounds for $R.$

Comment: did you mean R as lwer bound? @StephenDonovan

Comment: I meant $R^2,$ is there any reason it should be $R$? The lower bound is a paraboloid, not a cone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates,

Paraboloid surface is given by $z = r^2$ and surface $z^2 - 2 = x^2 + y^2$ is given by $z^2 - 2 = r^2$

So at the intersection of both surfaces,

$2 + r^2 = r^4 \implies r = \sqrt2$

So limits of integration are,

$r^2 \leq z \leq \sqrt{r^2+2}, 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Now i Understood my error. I though about the equation $r^4 = r^2+2$ but then I got stuck for I obtained $r = \pm \sqrt{2}$. The negative solutions I needed to trash! :D

Comment: Note that it's not exactly a cone. For that, the relationship between $r$ and $z$ is linear. This is a hyperboloid.

Comment: @Hans-André-Marie-Stamm Yes note that $z^2 - 2 = r^2$ forms above $z = \sqrt2$ and below $z = - \sqrt2$ but the paraboloid forms only above $z = 0$ so the intersection is clearly above $z = 0$.

Comment: @Andrei agree with you on that. Will edit.